# open API, I want to add description to remote schema

Tags: swagger, openapi

I reference an external schema for a property but I want to add my own description.

```
myProp:
  allOf:   
    - $ref: "https://opensource.zalando.com/problem/schema.yaml#/Problem"
    - type: object
```

Swagger editor tells me

Could not resolve reference: Could not resolve pointer /Problem does not exist in document

It looks like it will only allow allOf, for locally defined objects.  Is that correct?

Comment: Your definition is syntactically valid and works fine for me (i.e. no errors) in https://editor.swagger.io. That said, this particular example does not need `allOf`, you can write `myProp:` and the next line just `$ref: "https://opensource.zalando.com/problem/schema.yaml#/Problem"`. Do you use https://editor.swagger.io or a locally hosted editor? Can you post your complete OpenAPI YAML file?

Comment: @Helen Where do I put the description for myProp them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger: Add description with ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003348/swagger-add-description-with-ref)