# Swagger/OpenAPI $ref Included in Description Tags

Tags: swagger, openapi

Is it possible to reference or to insert text within a multiline description tag? For example:

```
description: |
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla ex a tincidunt 
  gravida. Integer ex sem, tristique non malesuada ac, scelerisque suscipit eris.

  <<<Insert text here>>>

  Morbi ac mauris at sapien interdum dapibus nec ac augue. Phasellus a nunc id magna pulvinar 
  maximus id id tellus.
```

The problem is anything like $ref: "#/schemas/disclaimer" is interpreted as literal text.

The closest I found here was this [Swagger: Add description with ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003348/swagger-add-description-with-ref), but that's for schemas and not the same thing.